# How could you randomly exclude/delete elements from an array that satisfy some condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

For example, if I had a 1x100 array, and it contained 90 0's, I'd like to somehow exclude 80 of those 0's chosen at random. I've been struggling with this problem for a while and I've made very little progress unfortunately.

Comment: Can you design your filter function to be probabilistic? For example: `lambda x: x != 0 and random.random() > 0.2`. Then you filter out 80% of the x's that are 0

Comment: It's easier to select the elements that you want to keep.  Then it's a simple matter of indexing with the list/array.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to keep the original array, or get a new array with 80 of the 0s removed?

Comment: @Nick My goal is to get a new array with 80 of the 0s, such that the shape of the new array would be 1x20.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `numpy` tag:

```py
import numpy as np

def solution(arr, value, size):
    return np.delete(arr, np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(arr==value), size, False))

arr = np.array([0]*90 + [1]*10)
np.random.shuffle(arr)

print(solution(arr, 0, 80)) # [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
print(solution(arr, 0, 90)) # [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
print(solution(arr, 0, 100)) # Raises error (expected behavior)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Python approach.

Determine indices of the elements meeting the criteria:

```
candidate_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if data == 0]
```

Choose indices to remove:

```
removed_indices = random.sample(candidate_indices, 80)
```

Remove them, by building a list without the corresponding elements:

```
result = [x for i, x in enumerate(data) if i not in removed_indices]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach, it is not very efficient, but it should be robust.

```
def progressivelyExcludeItem(item, arr, maxExclusions):
    """
    @param item the item value that will be progressively excluded
    @param arr the list from which we will exclude
    @param maxExclusions the maximum number of excluded items 
    """

    excludeIndices = [i for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x == item]
    excludeIndices = random.shuffle(excludeIndices)[:maxExclusions]

    for i in excludeIndices.sort().reversed():
        arr.pop(i)
```

Time complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: I think this code does't work.  if you pop the ith element, the bigger indices get all shifted, and now the random shuffling doesn't match the existing array anymore. What I think is that you should first build a list of indices to exclude, and then filter the array with those indices (I think there should be an easy way to do that in numpy)

Comment: indeed, classic mistake. fix is simply to iterate backwards, I will edit this now

Comment: get the first 80th values from  `random.shuffle(range(len(arr)))`, then sort this smaller "exclusion indices", and then iterate backward for popping them out

Comment: (currently there is still the same bug, as you reversed a shuffled array, see my above comment for fix)

Comment: You are correct, but the approach you posted is not sound either because the "exclusion indices" list may not contain all the indices needed. A rework is needed, I will post another approach.

Comment: ah yes, indeed. You need to first get all the indexes that match the zero value. Then do some random shufffle / splice on that part.

Comment: `for i in excludeIndices.sort().reversed():` ?